# C++ Primer 5th Ed - Question on accessibility of Derived-to-Base Conversion

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, c++20

In chapter 7 (Object Oriented Programming), below is the excerpts of the author when comes to accessibility of Derived-to-Base Conversion.

> Accessibility of Derived-to-Base Conversion
> Whether the derived-to-base conversion (§ 15.2.2, p. 597) is accessible depends on
> which code is trying to use the conversion and may depend on the access specifier
> used in the derived class’ derivation. Assuming D inherits from B:
> • User code may use the derived-to-base conversion only if D inherits publicly
> from B. User code may not use the conversion if D inherits from B using either
> protected or private.
> • Member functions and friends of D can use the conversion to B regardless of
> how D inherits from B. The derived-to-base conversion to a direct base class is
> always accessible to members and friends of a derived class.
> • Member functions and friends of classes derived from D may use the derived-tobase conversion if D inherits from B using either public or protected. Such
> code may not use the conversion if D inherits privately from B.

I don't understand the last 2 bullet points. Seems they are related to each other.
Appreciate any help with examples on it.
Thanks.

Final Note:
There's another thread with exact identical questions and feedback. Please refer to this link for further reading - [Derive* to Base* conversion in member function/friend function of base/derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28784738/derive-to-base-conversion-in-member-function-friend-function-of-base-derived-c)

Comment: Its exactly the same rules member functions and variables have.

Answer (score 1):

The last two bullet points are saying that if D inherits privately then the conversion is not available to further-derived types.

That is:

```
class B
{};
class D : private B
{};
class D2 : public D
{};
```

The list is simply formalizing that D2 and any friends do not have access to the B members of D, even though D itself and any friends of D do have such access.

Comment: The above will not work if class D: protected B {}. Example int main() { D d; B* b = &d; return 0}. The B* b = &d wll fail. However according to the author's last bullet excerpt, it mentioned it should work for protected as well.

Comment: @yapkm01 `main` is neither a member function nor a friend of `D`.

Comment: Author is talking about converting derived object to a base class  .. outside of classes .. not conversion within members of classes. So how does the last bullet point works .. best with examples

Comment: @yapkm01 Perhaps this paragraph is about doing it inside a class, but not inside the instance being converted.

Comment: No. I enclosed the excerpts from the author on this topic on the questionaire itself.

Comment: @yapkm01 The paragraph explicitly says 'Member functions and friends of classes derived from D may use the derived-tobase conversion'. You could create e.g. a static member function instead of main and try it out.

Comment: @Sebastian Ok. Let me dig more. Appreciate. Tx